# Error while issuing a state in Postgres Corda 4.6 OS

Tags: corda

Following are the error I got when trying to initiate a state in Corda 4.6OS using Postgres:
"net.corda.core.CordaRuntimeException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: net.corda.nodeapi.internal.persistence.CordaPersistence, which is a closeable resource, has been detected during flow checkpointing. Restoring such resources across node restarts is not supported. Make sure code accessing it is confined to a private method or the reference is nulled out."

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately with just this information it's hard to know what exactly happened.

Here's some examples of what could be happening.

look carefully through the stacktrace, if you're getting an unsupported runtime exception or other exceptions from code that's not in your control look around and make sure you're using packages / resources that line up with the cordapp template.

For example I had something like this for a couple hours because I was using the wrong junit package in my imports and the tests weren't initializing properly so you can get errors like this one and it won't be obvious at all why unfortunately.

Here's a link to the cordapp template, try to carefully check your flow / state to make sure all the imports are reasonable and you're using the right packages / gradle dependencies.

- https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-java
- https://github.com/corda/cordapp-template-kotlin

good luck